# local storage not changing the value

Tags: javascript, html

I am using local storage to store credentials and login details. It is working fine but when i tried to change that value it is not changing.

Here is the code for login.

**login.html**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">


                window.localStorage.setItem("login", "true");
                window.localStorage.setItem("email", data.email);
                window.localStorage.setItem("id", data.uid);    
                window.localStorage.setItem("name", data.name);                                 



</script>
```

and here is the code for logout. This one not working.

**logout.html**

```
window.localStorage.setItem("login", "false");
```

For some reason i am always getting `login = true` in logout.html file.

Any advise what am i doing wrong.

**Edit:**

Nothing wrong with the code. It is working fine. I was accessing the file directly thats why it was not changing.

Comment: you are using the js code under script tag same as in login.html ?

Comment: yes. I am using it inside <script> like in login.html page.

Comment: It should be working. You can see if values are being written to localStorage by opening the console in Chrome/Firefox. Press `f12` --> `Application` --> `Local Storage` (on the left side).

Comment: I checked there and still i can see login = true. checked in firefox and chrome

Comment: please provide a [mcve]`

Comment: Also, keep in mind that users can change these values by simply going through the console - not secure!

Comment: i am planning to use it on cordova. is it still unsecure?

Comment: @DanielA.White thanks for suggestions and down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me. You must have something else going on that isn't working.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    localStorage.setItem("login", true); 
    alert(localStorage.getItem('login'));

    localStorage.setItem("login", false);
    alert(localStorage.getItem('login'));

</script>
```

Works with quotes as well.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    localStorage.setItem("login", "true"); 
    alert(localStorage.getItem('login'));

    localStorage.setItem("login", "false");
    alert(localStorage.getItem('login'));

</script>
```

And here is checking...

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    localStorage.setItem("login", "true");

    if(localStorage.getItem("login")==="true"){
        alert('Value is True')
    }

    localStorage.setItem("login", "false");

    //login is false so this will not fire
    if(localStorage.getItem("login")==="true"){
        alert('Value is True')
    }

</script>
```

Comment: voted up. however i am getting down voted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

a guess: you are using somehting like

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("login"))
```

and its true. if that is the case its because any non empty string would yield true. if that is the case, try

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("login")==="true")
```

or

```
if(window.localStorage.getItem("login")!=="false")
```

Comment: it is working fine for login and can check on other page but when i try to logout. I am assuming it will make login = false. but that is not happening.

Comment: please add to your post exactly WHAT is working fine, and I mean the line of code that reads the value from the storage. if you have a problem something is clearly NOT working fine

Comment: I think its written clearly in question."For some reason i am always getting login = true"

Comment: @CalculatingMachine it's working fine, try again by clearing cache  or making changes to your code.

Comment: add the code that is reading from the local storage. let other people test your case. for some reason, your code fails. without seeing it, nobody knows what failed

Comment: voted up. however i am getting down voted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the item?

```
window.localStorage.removeItem("login");
window.localStorage.setItem("login", "false");
```

Comment: voted up. however i am getting down voted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps, you should use

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("login"))
```

this will get your item as a boolean true or false